# Error on `(interface-name) [typescript/tslint]` rule?

Tags: tslint

I get this tslint error, which I don't understand why. The interface does start with a capital letter.

`29 col 11 error| interface name must start with a capitalized I (interface-name) [typescript/tslint]`

```
S> 29 interface Props {
   30   answerQuestion: (answerQuestion: AnswerQuestion) => void;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`interface-name` rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/interface-name/) requires that all interfaces being with the capital letter `I`. This is to distinguish interfaces from classes (since an interface is not a value, but a class is). In your case, you could correct your code by naming your interface `IProps`.

Comment: If you need to, you can add this line above the interface declaration to ignore the error: `// tslint:disable-next-line:interface-name`

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding below code in your tslint.json =>

```
{
  "extends": ["tslint:recommended", "tslint-react", "tslint-config-prettier"],
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "config/**/*.js",
      "node_modules/**/*.ts",
      "coverage/lcov-report/*.js"
    ]
  },
  "rules": {
    "interface-name" : [true, "never-prefix"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify Your tslint.json

```
{
  "extends": [
    "tslint:recommended",
    "tslint-react",
    "tslint-config-prettier"
  ],
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "config/**/*.js",
      "node_modules/**/*.ts"
    ]
  },
  "interface-name" : [true, "never-prefix"] // <-- Include this line
}
```